# CrossTable and Loop do not like each other

Tags: r

I am trying to get a set of cross tables with 70 variables. But no matter what I did, R kept generating the "function" back to me. I tried to move `substitute` after `CrossTable` but R seemed to have trouble using `list(i=as.name(x))`.

```
library(gmodel)

Independent_List <- colnames(Comorbidity)[1:70]
Comorbidity_Table <- lapply(Independent_List, function(x) {
  substitute(CrossTable(i ,
                        Comorbidity$sleep,
                        prop.c = TRUE,
                        prop.r = FALSE,
                        prop.t = FALSE,
                        prop.chisq = FALSE,
                        data =Comorbidity),
             list(i=as.name(x)))
})

lapply(Comorbidity_Table, summary)

[[1]]
Length  Class   Mode 
     8   call   call 

[[2]]
Length  Class   Mode 
     8   call   call 

[[3]]
Length  Class   Mode 
     8   call   call
```

The goal is to try to make a table with specific cell numbers and column percentage and merge with my looped glm results.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using a much simpler method to solve this problem:

```
Tables <- lapply(Table_Data[, 1:11], function(x){table(x, Table_Data$TSD,exclude = NA)}) 
Prop_Tabs <- lapply(Tables[1:11], function(x){prop.table(x,2)})
```